# Adding tabs within activity in android

Tags: java, android, layout, view, tabs

I would like to create a tabbed view which has item description on top and a tabbed view at the bottom to populate its details. Something like the following image
[image]

Any suggestions or links to tutorials to achieve this?

Thanks,
Noorul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip` inside a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`:  PagerTabStrip inside ViewPager. There are plenty of examples online, here is one: https://gist.github.com/pboos/4535406